# Why is Adobe Flash asking to update when I don't have it installed?

Tags: windows-7, flash, uac

I was shown a UAC prompt while working asking me if I wanted to allow Adobe Flash to run.

(Looked identical to the first screen shot here: https://forums.adobe.com/message/4563117 )

Trouble is, I don't actually have Adobe Flash installed (or Adobe Reader for that matter). I use Chrome for both Flash and PDF content so I don't need either. (I answered *No* as I figured no good could come from allowing it to run.)

Where did the UAC prompt come from? Using Process Explorer, I found the process was called consent.exe but the trail went cold from there.

Is there a way to find out if I do actually have Adobe Flash installed? There's nothing named Adobe in either *Program Files* folders nor in the Control Panel list.

Any ideas please?

UPDATE: I've gone through the list of software I have installed, searching for **___ installs Adobe Flash** and found Skype as a possible culprit.

As the UAC prompt only happens once a day, is there any way I can confirm if this is the case?

Comment: Only two possible explanations exists.  You either actually do have it installed or what you see is actually a fake "flash update".  "I found the process was called consent.exe but the trail went cold from there."  based on this fact alone its a fake update.

Answer (score 0):

If it was just one time and you don't know how to trigger it, it's gonna be difficult to discern where it came from.

Anyway, I'd suggest you take a look at [Sysinternals' Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) - you might find some reg keys in 'Run'.
Also, check out your scheduled tasks (I don't remember if Autoruns show them).

Comment: If it happens again, is there anything I can do to work out where it came from?

Comment: Sysinternals' Sysmon would be your best shot - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dn798348
But it could get somewhat overwhelming with too many results.